# cTrader FIX API's Price field in new single order message

Tags: fix-protocol

I have a question about cTrader FIX API's Price field 44 in new order single message.

I found this in FIX Specification Version 2.16.1

https://help.ctrader.com/fix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pysa.png)

My question is that if I submit merket order with Price field 44, can I control the slippage of this merket order?

And If I set Price field, bigger slippage than I set never occurs?

I want to know whether cTrader FIX API supports " Market Range " order and it can avoid to excessive slippage or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The information in the cTrader specification document is ambiguous. You should contact their technical support to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Tag 44 is only used for limit orders. There is no slippage in limit orders since the order is filled at a price better or equal to the requested one. If you need more information just create a thread in ctrader.com